How can I get Altium's (v24) DRC to detect a missconnected via?
I use the remove pad shapes in altium, sometimes it doesn't work (ver 24.6.1 and some other v24 versions). Is there a way to get the DRC to throw a warning when the trace does not have a via connection with a ring around it?


I know you know, but maybe somebody else doesn't: Many Altium answers are found here: https://forum.live.altium.com

Software design questions are acceptable. I am aware, we can ask Altium questions on this site. Sometimes you get better and quicker answers here.
